# looking to power 3.5" drive before connecting to SATA→Thunderbolt2 adapter

Tags: hard-disk, sata, thunderbolt, adapter

I currently have a Segate GoFlex 22-pin SATA to Thunderbolt2 adapter (see images below) where you can switch in and out different 2.5-inch laptop hard drives. The adapter works great, but I would also like to hook up 3.5-inch drives in the same way. The problem is that the adapter provides insufficient power to run the larger 3.5" drive.

I am trying to figure out if something along these lines exists ...

1. a 22-pin SATA (male) to 22-pin SATA (female) that can accept power for the 3.5-drive and plug onto my existing SATA→Thunderbolt2 adapter, or
2. a 22-pin SATA splitter where I could use one side of the split to send power to my 3.5" drive and the other side of the split to connect to my existing SATA→Thunderbolt2 adapter?

Also open to any other workable solutions. Thanks!!

[image][image]

Comment: I think your issue is that, whilst Thunderbolt has a 12v rail, your adapter doesn't. 2.5" drives will run on only the 5v rail available in USB. 3.5" drives must have 12v. By skimping on the design, your adapter is cheaper [& I'd bet mainly a USB-inspired design internally]. I'd just buy an adapter with an external power supply, because you'll fry something if you send 12v where 5v is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the power to your HDD by anything.

What I already actually did:

1. Use a home power network -> PATA adapter to generate a PATA power:

[image]
[image]

2. Use a PATA -> SATA power adapter to convert it to a SATA power:

[image]

3. Use a SATA data cable to connect your HDD to your system:

[image]

**I could not find a solution quickly, but very likely also a solution without a PATA component exists.**

---

Advantages:

- If you have some super-oldie archive on PATA HDDs, you can access also them
- It is very likely the cheapest solution
- It is very flexible solution (you can use all the parts for many other tasks, too)

Disadvantages:

- You need to cable a lot
- It won't be very beautiful
- Many part also means many possible points of error (although all the parts are far enough simple to become reliable)

(P.s. I have no affiliation to any of the images)